# boost asio service returning too soon

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, service, asio

been trying to solve this problem i am facing concerning the io_service object. The code in question in so:

```
    void connect_handler(const error_code &ec,iterator iterator){
        cout<<"Connect handler"<<endl;
    }

    void resolver_handler(const error_code &ec,iterator iterator,boost::asio::io_service &io){
        cout<<"Resolver handler..."<<endl;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io);
        boost::asio::async_connect(socket,iterator,&connect_handler);
    }

    int main(){
        boost::asio::io_service io;
        resolver resolver(io);
        resolver::query query("example.com","http");
        resolver.async_resolve(query,boost::bind(resolver_handler,boost::asio::placeholders::error,boost::asio::placeholders::iterator,boost::ref(io)));
        cout<<io.run()<<endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Tried the same thing in another simple example, with everything running as intended:

```
void printTwo(const error_code& ec,boost::asio::deadline_timer &timer,boost::asio::io_service &io){
    cout<<"print two"<<endl;
}

void printOne(const error_code& ec,boost::asio::deadline_timer &timer,boost::asio::io_service &io){
    cout<<"print one"<<endl;
    timer.async_wait(boost::bind(printTwo,boost::asio::placeholders::error,boost::ref(timer),boost::ref(io)));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(io,boost::posix_time::seconds(3));
    timer.async_wait(boost::bind(printOne,boost::asio::placeholders::error,boost::ref(timer),boost::ref(io)));
    cout<<io.run()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My assumptions is that the service object blocks until all work is done; also the thread that calls the run function is the thread that the handler functions are called from. So, why does the second block of code work as intended, but not the first? thanks in advance.

Comment: Your socket goes out of scope.

Comment: I didn't completely read your question, but I think you should check out https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__work.html   If io_service runs out of work, it'll return from that call. By putting this into the io_service work queue, it will simply stay there doing nothing, making io_service think it needs to keep going.

Comment: I'm assuming `io.run()` is returning too quickly, it's not completely clear.

Comment: And your socket goes out of scope. @tkausl is right.

Comment: In your second example, the `deadline_timer` is the thing that's keeping the `io_service` alive. For three seconds, there is "work to be done", and when that three seconds expires (or the timer is reset) that work is "completed".

Answer (score 0):

`io.run()` in your program will return as soon as the `io_service` thinks it's done with the work it has to do. This could happen *between* operations or maybe when the last async callback is called (I'm not completely sure).

Use a [`work` object](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__work.html) to inform the `io_service` to keep running, and when you reset that work object, the `io_service`'s `run()` call should return once it's done executing any pending operations.

The basic use is something like this:

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::io_service::work work(io_service);
// ...
io_service.run(); // Blocks here
```

And usually in another thread or maybe in one of the async callbacks, you do this:

```
work.reset();
```

And some time later, `run()` will return.